# Inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to learn about inheritance. I've tried to make a class called ProductionWorker that is derived from Employee. I'm trying to follow the model given by [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) website. However, it seems like the inheritance isn't working because I get errors in the main function saying that name, number, and date are not set in this scope. What is wrong with the code?

Program.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
ProductionWorker worker;

cout<<"What is the employee name?"<<endl;
cin>>name;
worker.setName(name);

cout<<"What is the employee number?"<<endl;
cin>>number;
worker.setNumber(number);

cout<<"What is the employee hire date?"<<endl;
cin>>date;
worker.setDate(date);

cout<<"Employee Information:"<<endl;
cout<<worker.getName()<<endl;
cout<<worker.getNumber()<<endl;
cout<<worker.getDate()<<endl;
cout<<worker.getShift()<<endl;
cout<<worker.getPayRate()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

employee.h:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_
#define EMPLOYEE_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee{
protected:
    string name;
    int number;
    string date;
public:
    Employee(string a="", int b=0, string c=""){
    name=a;
    number=b;
    date=c;
    }
void setName(string);
void setNumber(int);
void setDate(string);

string getName();
int getNumber();
string getDate();
};

class ProductionWorker: public Employee{
private:
    int shift;
    double pay;
public:
    ProductionWorker(int d=1, double e=10.0, string a="", int b=0, string c=""):Employee(a, b, c){
        shift=d;
        pay=e;
    }
    int getShift();
    double getPayRate();
};
```

employee.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

//EMPLOYEE
void Employee::setName(string a){
    name=a;
}
void Employee::setNumber(int b){
    number=b;
}
void Employee::setDate(string c){
    date=c;
}

string Employee::getName(){
    return name;
}
int Employee::getNumber(){
    return number;
}
string Employee::getDate(){
    return date;
}

//PRODUCTION WORKER
int ProductionWorker::getShift(){
    return shift;
}
double ProductionWorker::getPayRate(){
    return pay;
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. Right now the code is unreadable. Chances are that you find the error while fixing the indentation.

Comment: Re: `using namespace std;`: please don't.

Comment: @PeteBecker why not? I personally think that for a small example like this it hardly seems to matter.

Comment: @davmac - granted, in simple examples it is usually harmless. Nevertheless, it's a bad practice, and should always be discouraged. Especially in a forum like this, where 90% of the code seems to use it, presumably from ignorance and not a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should declare *name*, *number* and *date* before you use it, in **Program.cpp**. You try to get input into symbol that compiler doesn't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is nothing to do with inheritance:

```
int main() {
    ProductionWorker worker;

    cout<<"What is the employee name?"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
```

You're reading into a variable called `name` but no such variable is in scope (i.e. declared in the `main()` function itself or globally). Though `name` is a member of the Employee class, you cannot use it as such in this way. (Consider: how would the compiler know *which* instance of Employee that you were wanting to set the `name` of? And, of course, if you *could* read directly into the instance variable, there would be no need to call `worker.setName(...)` afterwards).

You should just declare `name` as a local variable, by specifying its type:

```
int main() {
    string name;
    ProductionWorker worker;

    cout<<"What is the employee name?"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
```

Now `cin>>name;` reads into the local variable `name` that is declared within the `main()` function. (I took the liberty of fixing your indentation). In a similar way, you need declarations for `date` and `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the variables that `cin` needs to read into.

Just add

```
string name;
int number;
string date;
```

At the top of function `main`.